# SQL End of Line from Windows Format to Unix

Tags: sql-server, newline, eol

Is there a way in SQL to convert end of line from `CRLF` to `LF` (Windows to Unix).  When I attempt a query to replace `CR` `CHAR(13)` with nothing or replace `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` with just `CHAR(10)`, it still keeps the `CR`.

```sql
SELECT Config = REPLACE(Config, CHAR(13), '')
FROM dbo.ConfigArchive`
```

and have tried

```sql
SELECT Config = REPLACE(REPLACE(Config, CHAR(13), ''),CHAR(10), CHAR(10)), DownloadTime
FROM dbo.NCM_ConfigArchive
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please show the query you tried to use in your question. And show the actual and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

one quick fix can be opening your file with Notepad++, and then going to Edit-->EOL Conversion --> Unix/osx format (should be checked)